# Axios Response Data not saved in State

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I have a custom hook `useServerStatus` that fetches from a RESTful API with axios. Checking the network tab, the response went through fine, I can see all my data. Using `console.log` to print out the result or using `debugger` to check the result in the browser works flawlessly. However, calling the setState method that I get from `useState` will not save the response data.

**ServerStatus Interface** *(ServerStatus.ts)*

```
interface ServerStatus {
  taskid: string
  taskmodule: string
  taskident?: string
  status: string
  server: string
  customer: string
}
```

**useServerStatus Hook** *(useServerStatus.ts)*

```
export default function useServerStatus() {
  const [serverStatus, setServerStatus] = useState<ServerStatus[][]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchServerStatus();
  }, []);

  const fetchServerStatus = () => {
    axios.get<ServerStatus[][]>(`${config.apiURL}/servers`)
      .then(res => setServerStatus(res.data));
  }

  return serverStatus;
}
```

**Network Tab**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvABl.png

The first request you see in the network tab is handled the same exact way, no problems there.

**React Developer Console**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClF30.png

Comment: Try moving your data fetching code into useEffect hook? That's the suggested way of async data fetching from the docs

Comment: @konekoya I just tried it, same result as before

Comment: First of all you have no dependency array in the useEffect, I think what that does is sending in undefined. Try inserting an empty array as dependency if you only want to fetch the server status on the first render.

Comment: @MartinZ I actually have that, I must have missed it when copying over and formatting the code. I'll edit it in

Comment: @NilsFahle Alright, nice. And I assume if you console.log res.data you get the same results from the network tab?

Comment: Could you provide a runnable code example?

Comment: @MartinZ I think we might be onto something. I just console.log-ed the `res` object and I found [this weird discrepancy](https://i.imgur.com/IstVeBr.png)

Comment: @NilsFahle Alright, progress. Im not familiar with TS, but does the ServerStatus interface object match with the result objects you're getting from axios?

Comment: @MartinZ yes, the data matches up

Comment: @NilsFahle: Please do not include answers into your question. You can post a self-answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question:

I figured out that the problem wasn't about data not being saved in state, but data not correctly being received by axios.

I fixed it with a workaround. Instead of returning a `ServerStatus[][]` in my backend, I returned a `ServerStatus[]`. I was able to use this data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const fetchServerStatus = () => {
    axios.get<ServerStatus[][]>(`${config.apiURL}/servers`)
      .then(res => { setServerStatus(res.data) });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the lesson here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html the most obvious thing that jumps out to me is that you aren't returning the state variable serverStatus in your code vs. the example is returning "isOnline". Try to match this by returning serverStatua in your custom effect to see if it helps.

Comment: I actually have that, I must have missed it when copying over and formatting the code. I've added it in the question, but the result stays the same.

Comment: Ok. Worth a shot.

Comment: Reviewing your updated post, did you try without the empty conditional variable array 2nd arg in use effect? Maybe it doesn't like that too since the doc says "make sure to only call other Hooks unconditionally" and shows all use effect calls with no conditional propevery arg at all.

Comment: Also can you add code where you call and use the custom hook? To clarify the question are you saying that wherever you call the custom hook it is NOT receiving the updated info as if the setServerStatus wasn't called right? And you'vre already tried putting a console.log in your axios then promise to confirm the .then is actually reached at runtime?